# ¿Se puede cambiar el tipo del decimal [coma o punto] en java?

Tags: java, float

Me quiero referir a que si es posible, por ejemplo, si declaro un float e introduzco el decimal 17,2 se pueda introducir de la forma 17.2 también y no me de error.

Comment: podrias recibirlo como un String y luego usar el metodo replace para cambiar la coma por el punto

Comment: El punto es un operador y cuando estas en el código es lo que tienes que usar, es como si quisieras cambiar el operador +.
Otra cosa es a la entrada por teclado de tu programa, si es este el caso puedes usar String.replaceAll() o si quieres usar un evento al pulsar una tecla y si esta es . Remplazarlo por , o viceversa.
Para este caso investiga la clase keyevent